# What happened after setting up MySQL? Ubuntu server changed to desktop

Tags: mysql

I set up a MySQL database and when I restarted the computer it is now a desktop.
I am frustrated by this and I want to know how I can revert it

Comment: Two questions: (0) which version of Ubuntu Server are you running (1) what are the exact commands you ran to install MySQL Server?

Comment: I am using 20.04 and the command was an apt get of MySQL and modified the php.ini file for an extension

Comment: This seems incomplete. If you check your installation history logs in `/var/log/apt`, then you’ll see which exact command was entered and what the resulting packages were. From there, you may be able to uninstall them.

Comment: My old comment was flawed. fixed the cmds: There are multiple mysql packages. Which one did you choose? If you don't remember, run `apt-cache --names-only search mysql` and you will get a list of the possible options. Or you can run `apt search mysql | grep .*mysql.*installed.*` and find the option that says [installed] and not [installed,automatic].

Comment: Apt shows you the proposed package changes and provides an opportunity for you to review and approve-or-refuse the proposed install. If you approve without reading the output, then any surprises or frustration are not apt's fault.